# Get name of month displayed in very simple dropdownbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have created a very simple dropdownbox:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="MonthDropDown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Code Behind:

```
MonthDropDown.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 12);
MonthDropDown.SelectedIndex = DateTime.Now.Month;
MonthDropDown.DataBind();
```

Is there any way to get the `MonthDropDown`(my dropdownbox) to display name of month, instead of the numeric value of the month. I'm thinking it could be something like

```
DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName(MonthDropDown.SelectedIndex)?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is culture-specific of course, so look for it under the `CultureInfo` class:

```
string monthName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(monthIndex);
```

You can set the month names as the values in the ListBox:

```
MonthDropDown.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
    .Select(monthIndex => 
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(monthIndex))
    .ToArray();
```

You can also use keys/values if you still want the selected *value* to be the index:

```
MonthDropDown.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
    .Select(monthIndex=> 
        new ListItem(
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(monthIndex), 
            monthIndex.ToString()))
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you mean?

```
for (int n = 1; n <= 12; ++n)
    MonthDropDown.Items.Add(n, DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName(n));

MonthDropDown.SelectedIndex = DateTime.Now.Month - 1; // note -1
```

Note that `MonthDropDown.SelectedValue` will be the one-based value (1 = January), but `MonthDropDown.SelectedIndex` will be zero-based (0 = January).